# How can you create an array of integers that roughly averages to a given number?

Tags: arrays, math, language-agnostic

I'm not trying to find the average of an array, I'm trying to create an array that will roughly average to a desired number.

My use case is that I have 2 stepper motors that each need to perform a **smooth** movement over roughly the same amount of time. Steppers move in discrete steps with an integer ms delay between these steps. I need to be able to control the speed of the "faster" motor (ie: the one that needs to take more total steps with a smaller, constant delay between steps) and the speed of the "slower" motor should adjust as needed.

Consider the case where Motor A needs to take 100 steps and Motor B needs to take 150. The delay between Motor B's steps must be 1ms so the delay between Motor A's steps would then be 1.5ms. This doesn't work since the step delay must be an integer.

To that end, I believe you can solve this problem by generating an array with a length equal to the number of total steps where each element is an integer that, overall, averages to that 1.5ms delay.  The example for this case would simply be:

```
motor_a_step_delays = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2 ... 100 elements total ...]
```

---

My issue is that I can't seem to find a good way to create this array. The integer elements should be "close" (for lack of a better word).  Something like `[51, 1, 1, ... 97 more 1's...]` would be correct, but not result in smooth, even movement.

This problem feels like it's been solved, but I don't know how to even start searching for it. This seems like it'd have utility in CNC, robotics, or game design applications.

Answer (score 1):

As usual, the act of typing out my issue made me stop and think about what's actually happening.

Fundamentally, the array would only contain the floor and ceil of the desired average delay.  If the desired average was 2.25, the final array would be some combination of 2 and 3, but never 1 or 4.  Once I realized that, it seems so simple that the number of ceils and floors is proportional to how far the desired delay is from its ceil/floor.  In other words, 2.25 would need an array of 75% 2's and 25% 3's.  Easy!

Here is what I ended up with (Elixir):

```
  def generate_step_delays(steps, desired_delay) do
    desired_delay_ceil = ceil(desired_delay)
    desired_delay_floor = floor(desired_delay)
    # The ratio of ceils to floors needed
    ratio = desired_delay - desired_delay_floor

    ceil_list = List.duplicate(desired_delay_ceil, round(steps * ratio))
    floor_list = List.duplicate(desired_delay_floor, steps - length(ceil_list))

    ceil_list
    |> Enum.concat(floor_list)
    |> Enum.shuffle()
  end
```

This implementation randomizes the final array since that works best for my case.  However, it would be simple to swap out `Enum.shuffle` and evenly distribute the numbers if needed.

Comment: this would probably have been my approach as well :) Now, if you need to get as close to 2.25 as possible (rather than just sufficiently close) there might be ways to improve this (at least, when the number of cycles is not divisible by four). but i digress